# Cut a string between two variable sub strings in shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have filenames as below(omitted the actual names)
I need to extract the filename between the filename_prefix and runid 
Problem here being the filename changes and is 2-5 fields long. 
I have been using this

```
echo "filename_prefix_filename_filename_filename_runid_date_part-r-00020-c68fdc43-53bc-4aa9-a96b-2692ae2aa508.orc " | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' RS='filename_prefix' FS='runid'
```

This works fine on the command line but I need to pass RS and FS as variables which I am not able to do so because

```
echo of file name |awk -v file_p=$file_prefix -v r_id=_$RUN_ID 'NF > 1 {print $1}' RS=file_p FS=r_id
```

the above command doesn't work.

Filenames:

```
filename_prefix_filename_filename_filename_runid_date_part-r-00020-c68fdc43-53bc-4aa9-a96b-2692ae2aa508.orc

filename_prefix_filename_filename_runid_date_part-r-00020-c68fdc43-53bc-4aa9-a96b-2692ae2aa508.orc
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are still setting `RS` and `FS` *outside* the `awk` script itself, you use the shell variable, not `awk` variables.

```
... | awk 'NF > 1 {print $1}' RS="$file_prefix" FS="$RUN_ID"
```

Alternately, you can use

```
... | awk -v RS="$file_prefix" -v FS="$RUN_ID" 'NF > 1 {print $1}'
```

or

```
... | awk -v file_p="$file_prefix" -v runid="$RUN_ID" 'BEGIN{RS=file_p; FS=runid}; NF > 1 {print $1}'
```

The last one, though, is unnecessarily indirect.

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm. Understood the working of awk, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

The assignments to `RS` and `FS` are wrong. You cannot use Awk variables here; they are interpreted simply as static strings (which is the only arrangement which makes sense anyway).

```
awk 'NF > 1 {print $1}' RS="$file_prefix" FS="_$RUN_ID"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do the same in `bash`, although a two step process

```
$ f="filename_prefix_filename_filename_filename_runid_date_part-r-00020-c68fdc43-53bc-4aa9-a96b-2692ae2aa508.orc"; 
  pre="filename_prefix_"; 
  run="_runid*";

$ ff=${f%$run}; echo ${ff#$pre}

filename_filename_filename
```